# ionic2: can't apply background color to button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using ionic2,,,, I can't apply any css properties in buttons I used this code to built buttons: 

Login
then the button didn't appear in the output although any other element css effects appears

Comment: Please share your html and css

Comment: @Duannx <button ion-button color="danger"></button> this code should generate red button but in my project It didn't  although It works correctly in another projectand in my project when I save changes in file.scss the ionic generate two other files file.min.css & file.css

Comment: are you using any plungin or extension in your project?

Comment: @Duannx no it is just the design of pages, I only used Ionic2RatingModule but it is not the problem